# Pattern with dots in symfony2 routing

Tags: php, regex, symfony

I have 2 bundles : one for my website, and one for my API. My API URL is `mywebsite` and my website URL is `www.website.com`.

I use the `host` parameter to filter routes by host, and I want to allow `localhost` on one of my bundle for local development purpose (without creating a vhost).

But get this error :

```
Parameter "domain" for route "tv_home" must match "[^\.]++" ("((www\.)?mywebsite\.fr|localhost)" given) to generate a corresponding URL.
```

I understand that it comes from the regex I use here :

```
domain: "((www\.)?mywebsite\.fr|localhost)"
```

How can I achieve my goal if I can't use dots in this regex ?

Here is my master routing file :

```
tv_api:
    resource: "@TVApiBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host:     "api.mywebsite.fr"
    prefix:   /

tv_site:
    resource: "@TVSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host:     "{domain}"
    defaults:
            domain: "((www\.)?mywebsite\.fr|localhost)"
    prefix:   /
```

Regards,

Comment: Where is your tv_home route is it the same as tv_site ? is changing hosts file of your system and not using routing configuration for this an option to achieve your goal in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default domain value does not affect is route will match or not. Because of domain if always present in request it is useful only for generating URLs. There are requirements for that purpose (btw [^.]++ would be default requirement for domain).

```
tv_site:
    resource: "@TVSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host:     "{domain}"
    defaults:
        domain: "mywebsite.fr"
    requirements:
        domain: "((www\.)?mywebsite\.fr|localhost)"
    prefix:   /
```

It should work. But all routes will be generated with mywebsite.fr (in case of absolute url). You can use service container parameter.

```
tv_site:
    resource: "@TVSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host:     "{domain}"
    defaults:
        domain: "%domain%"
    requirements:
        domain: "((www\.)?mywebsite\.fr|localhost)"
    prefix:   /
```

As example easiest way to define this parameter is in parameter.yml. Or I think you can also ommit defaults key completely.

Comment: Hello, you are right, I was using "defaults" instead of "requirements" and didn't noticed it. It works with "requirements". I'll remember that lesson : stop the code when it's time to go sleep :p