# How do I ignore the top level domain when using host to route to a subdomain in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, routes, tld

I have a website that I'm testing locally using domain.lc. The website has a subdomain sub.domain.lc that routes to a different controller, like this:

```
my_bundle:
    host:     sub.domain.lc
    resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

The subdomain routes to my bundle because of the host, but I would like it to also route to this bundle using sub.domain.com. Is there a way to ignore the top level domain using the host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use placeholder like this:

```
my_bundle:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host:     "{domain}"
    defaults:
        domain: "%domain%"
    requirements:
        domain: "sub\.domain\.(lc|com)"
```

But there is a problem with generating absolute URLs. It depends on where your app is currently running (loc or com) and you need to specify it as container parameter (parameters.yml is good place). [Link to similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112100/pattern-with-dots-in-symfony2-routing/29117770).

Answer (score 0):

Although kba did provide an answer that helped me very much and I will in fact accept his answer as the right one, I want to show you what my route ended up looking like:

```
my_bundle:
    host:     sub.domain.{tld}
    resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    requirements:
        tld: lc|nl
    defaults:
        tld: nl
```

I didn't use the Service Container Parameter in my route, because I know my domain won't change. Only my top level domain can change.